# How can I align the itemize with its title?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, itemize

I want to align the list of items with its title, all start from the left margin of the page. For decreasing the space between the items, I have used "compactitem" package. But the result is like this:

**Name list**

- item 1
- item 2
- item 3

But I want the bullets align with title "Name list" (i,e with no indent). I used \noindent for each item but it doesn't change. How can I do it?

Comment: Use the `wide` option of the `enumitem` package. No \noindent required.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You will have to show us the minimal code to produce the shown image. Like this it will just be guessing.

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution using the `enumitem` package instead of `paralist`. Its `wide` option is made for that:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

Here’s a compact itemize environment with bullets aligned with the left margin:

\noindent
\begin{itemize}[wide, nosep, labelindent = 0pt, topsep = 1ex]
\item[\textbf{Name list}]
\item A first item
\item A second item
\item Another item
\end{itemize}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\end{document}
```

[image]